# Want to Create an Array button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a button using array but when i try to write text in text input and try to create a button it doesn't change the value.

```js
function ready() {

  var family = ["demo1", "demo2", "demo3", "demo4", "demo5", "demo6"];

  function btns() {
    var btn = $("<button>" + family[i] + "</button>")
    $(btn).attr("data-search", family[i])
    $(btn).appendTo("#buttons")
  }

  var submit = $("<button>Submit</button>");
  var text = $("<input type='text' name='text'>");
  $(text).appendTo("#submit");
  $(submit).appendTo("#submit");



  for (i = 0; i < family.length; i++) {

    btns();
  }

  $(submit).on("click", function() {
    var textBtn = text.val();
    family.push(textBtn);
    btns();


  })

}
ready();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="buttons"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div id="gif"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div id="submit"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: what is your `submit` function? pay attention to the names. Then you do `var submit = ...`

Comment: i remove the submit function and try to run it still no luck

Comment: post your html code

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? The code is commented to show you the steps

```js
var family = ["demo1", "demo2", "demo3", "demo4", "demo5", "demo6"];

// for each family add a button
const buttons = family.map(el => $(`<button data-search="${el}">${el}</button>`));
$('#buttons').append(buttons);

function addButton() {
  // get the value of the text input
  const val = $('#button-text').val();
  // if the value is not empty
  if (val.trim().length) {
    // create the new button and append it
    const btn = $(`<button data-search="${val}">${val}</button>`);
    $('#buttons').append(btn);
    // add the val to the family array
    family.push(val);
    // add the button to the buttons array
    buttons.push(btn);
    // reset the input field
    $('#button-text').val('');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="buttons">
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" id="button-text"/>
  <button onClick="addButton()">Add Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your existing code is that you have declared the variable `i` in your for loop, but you are not incrementing the value when you manually add the new button.

If you update your submit button click event as follows, you will accomplish what you are looking for:

```
$(submit).on("click", function(){
    var textBtn = text.val();
    family.push(textBtn);
    console.log(family);
    btns();
    i++; // Added the increment of 'i' here.
});
```

However, I am sure there's a much more eloquent way of solving this problem that doesn't involve keeping track of the array index.

Answer (score 0):

Few things here

1. You may not need to create the input and the button using js. You can create it using html only
2. The `i` in the for loop is global, put a keyword before it and then pass the `family[i]` to the `btns` function

```js
var family = ["demo1", "demo2", "demo3", "demo4", "demo5", "demo6"];

function btns(val) {
  var btn = $("<button>" + val + "</button>")
  $(btn).attr("data-search", val)
  $(btn).appendTo("#buttons")
}
for (let i = 0; i < family.length; i++) {
  btns(family[i]);
}




$("#submitBtn").on("click", function() {
  var textBtn = $("#submitIp").val();
  btns(textBtn);


})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="buttons"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div id="gif"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div id="submit">
          <input type='text' id='submitIp' name='text'><button id='submitBtn'>Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

here, your loop is the main problem...you need to add element singularly

```js
 function ready(){

var family = ["demo1","demo2","demo3","demo4","demo5","demo6"];

      function btns(){
          var btn = $("<button>" + family[i] + "</button>");
          $(btn).attr("data-search", family[i])
          $(btn).appendTo("#buttons")
      }

      var submit = $("<button>Submit</button>");
          var text = $("<input type='text' name='text'>");
          $(text).appendTo("#submit");
          $(submit).appendTo("#submit");



      for (i=0; i < family.length; i++){

          btns();
      }

      $(submit).on("click", function(){
          var textBtn = text.val();
          // family.push(textBtn);
          var btn = $("<button>" + textBtn + "</button>");
          $(btn).attr("data-search", textBtn)
          $(btn).appendTo("#buttons")
      })

 }
  ready();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="buttons"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div id="gif"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div id="submit"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Also, I haven't change your code..just pasted your code on the correct block :)

Answer (score 0):

you are missing selector while getting input val

```js
function ready() {

  var family = ["demo1", "demo2", "demo3", "demo4", "demo5", "demo6"];

  function btns() {
    var btn = $("<button>" + family[i] + "</button>")
    $(btn).attr("data-search", family[i])
    $(btn).appendTo("#buttons")
  }

  var submit = $("<button>Submit</button>");
  var text = $("<input type='text' name='text'>");
  $(text).appendTo("#submit");
  $(submit).appendTo("#submit");



  for (i = 0; i < family.length; i++) {

    btns();
  }

  $(submit).on("click", function() {
    var textBtn = $( "input[name='text']" ).val();
    family.push(textBtn);
    btns();


  })

}
ready();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="buttons"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div id="gif"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div id="submit"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're referring `i` in your `btns` function. The recommended way is to create a scope for any variable. I prefer to use `let` and `const` to scope the variables.

You have to move the iteration into the `btns` function and create another function which is solely responsible to create a button with the text passed as a parameter. And call the create button function from your `btns` function. And easily you can reuse the create button function even for your `click` event handler.

The sample code can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/pop7vkzpx

Comment: There is no syntax error here. The variable `i` is declared without the var keyword, thus it has global scope.